# TestCafe: Page Models for Single Page Applications

Tags: testing, automated-tests, single-page-application, testcafe, pageobjects

I have been struggling to figure out the best way to represent a single page application within TestCafe, and was wondering if anyone out there could help me?

Currently I am structuring it like the following (fake page names of course).  I have greatly simplified it here for the sake of discussion, but the problem you should start to see is that as the app grows larger, the main page starts importing more and more.  And each of those imports have imports, which might have more imports.  So the cascading affect is causing TestCafe to drastically slow down when launching tests.

Does it make more sense to force the tests themselves to import all of the 'sections' they work with?  What about for longer workflow tests that hit a bunch of sections?  Does it still make sense then?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
import {Selector, t} from 'testcafe';
import {
    ConsumerSection,
    ManufacturerSection,
    SupplierSection,
    <AndSoOn>
} from './CarPageSections';

export class CarPage extends BasePage {

    // BasePage contains all of the Header, Footer, NavBar, SideBar, Action Flyouts

    CarSelectionTimer: Selector;
    ModelSelectionModal: ModelSelectionModal;
    SomeOtherModal: SomeOtherModal;

    // Section Selectors
    sectionPanels = {
        ConsumerSection: null as ConsumerSection,
        ManufacturerSection: null as ManufacturerSection,
        SupplierSection: null as SupplierSection,
        <AndSoOn>: null as <AndSoOn>
    };

    sections = {
        ConsumerSection: null as SectionControl,
        ManufacturerSection: null as SectionControl,
        SupplierSection: null as SectionControl,
        <AndSoOn>: null as SectionControl
    };

    constructor() {
        this.CarSelectionTimer = Selector('#car-selection-timer');

        // Sections
        this.sections = {
            ConsumerSection: new SectionControl('Consumer'),
            ManufacturerSection: new SectionControl('Manufacturer'),
            SupplierSection: new SectionControl('Supplier'),
            <AndSoOn>: new SectionControl('<AndSoOn>')
        };

        this.sectionPanels = {
            ConsumerSection: new ConsumerSection(this.sections.ConsumerSection.control),
            ManufacturerSection: new ManufacturerSection(this.sections.ManufacturerSection.control),
            SupplierSection: new SupplierSection(this.sections.SupplierSection.control),
            <AndSoOn>: new <AndSoOn>(this.sections.<AndSoOn>.control)
        };

        this.ModelSelectionModal = new ModelSelectionModal();
        this.SomeOtherModal = new SomeOtherModal();
    }

    async SomeActionToPerformOnThePage(params) {
        // DO STUFF
    }

    async SomeOtherActionToPerformOnThePage(params) {
        // DO STUFF
    }
}
```

Considerations to handle:

1. Constructors with parameters like ConsumerSection(control) above.
2. Using files to export multiple objects / classes to simplify importing in tests (or other models).

Questions to consider:

1. Should every model be decoupled from every other model?
2. Without coupling models, how do you make it as easy as possible to work with?  In other test frameworks, you can hand back a new page type upon a given method/action: i.e. LoginPage.Submit() returns HomePage().

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to determine the cause of the issue without your full page model. Your issue looks similar to this one: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4054. Please check that Github thread and apply the recommendations from it.
If this does not help, please share your full page model. If you cannot share it here, you can send it at support@devexpress.com

Comment: I have a few questions about this, and at least one potential issue.

How do you handle classes that have constructors with parameters?
"export default new ClassNameHere();" is not valid, and the parameter values won't exist until their usage: Example - A page with multiple sections handing down parent control selectors to make child selectors smarter.

Also, this does not appear to allow using aggregator files for exporting / importing.  Is that correct?

A file that does:
export * from 'file1';
export * from 'file2';
export * from 'file3';

Comment: The suggested solution was specific to that issue. It looks like your page model and your requirements for the page model are more complex than in the mentioned issue. So, perhaps, the workaround is not appropriate. Please share your tests and your page model with us. You can create a separate issue in our Github repository using the following link: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md

If you cannot share your project/tests/page model, you can send it at support@devexpress.com